# Enable gzip for node app running on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, gzip

I have a node app with a React front-end running on Node 14 as an Azure App Service.

The app consists of a middleman node server (on port 3000, running on express) that routes all API requests to another service (a .Net app running on a separate Azure App Service), and a React front-end that the user interacts with (running on port 3001). Everything seems to be working fine - both the local dev environment and the Azure service handle API requests as they should.

Looking a little closer, however, it seems that the local dev environment (typically running on a Mac) is gzipping all responses from the API, whereas the Azure service *isn't*. This is resulting in a ~90% increase in the size of the data that the middleman server is sending to the front-end React app when running in Azure as opposed to locally. For example, one of our API calls returns a response weighing ~33kB when running locally, but an identical request returns a ~500kB response.

I've tried specifying `Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Type` header, but this has no effect.

My initial thoughts are that the Azure service is configured differently to the local one, and that gzipping either isn't supported on Azure or hasn't been explicitly enabled. Alternatively, the Azure instance might be going through some kind of gateway that's stripping content encoding headers?

Does anyone have any insights into what I should try to get Azure to send gzipped responses?

Comment: Is this running on a regular Azure VM? Or is this architecture managed in a sub-product like App Service/etc.?

Comment: it's an App Service. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: What server is the "middleman" server you describe running? Express? nginx? Something else?

Comment: express. Question updated again!

Comment: Sorry for all the clarifying questions - the ".Net app" you describe, is that being served via IIS? Or does it handle the HTTP requests without any dependency as such? Have you established whether the upstream .NET application is returning the data uncompressed, or is the data coming uncompressed as it passes through your "middleman"? Can you share a [mre] of the code the middleman is running? Is the middleman using the `compression` middleware, or does it just pass the `gzip`ped data as more a transparent passthru?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I missed a small (but crucial) step: enabling compression on the Express server.

Installing and importing the `Compression` package, and adding the following to our server code solved the issue:

```
app.use(compression());
```

Without this the locally-running front-end was serving compressed data, but not the Azure-deployed version.